# Merging different dataframes together but index might not always be the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 11 different areas (P01, P02, ..., P11) and each area has some equipment identified by a code (INV 1-1, INV 1-2, ..., INV 8-4). The problem is that the number of equipment changes from area to area so, for example, P01 doesn't have the code INV 6-4, but P02 has it. But their values will always be on `index` array.

I have a dataframe called `allEquipAllAreas` which holds float values for every INV for each area. Here is an example:

```
P01-INV-1-1 P01-INV-1-2 P01-INV-1-3 P01-INV-1-4 P11-INV-7-2 P11-INV-7-3 P11-INV-7-4
   -0.52       1.89         1.61        1.59        2.02        1.29       -0.89
```

I created a for to go through all areas and fetch all equipment related to that area, so I would like to end up having a final dataframe (`heatMapInvdf`) as below but instead of "NaN" I'd like to put `allEquipAllAreas` on the respectively columns:

```
         P01  P02  P03  P04  P05  P06  P07  P08  P09  P10  P11
INV 1-1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
INV 1-2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
INV 1-3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  ...                             ...
INV 8-2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
INV 8-3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
INV 8-4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I have tried to merge them but couldn't achieve what I want, so did is what I have so far:

```
index = ['INV 1-1','INV 1-2','INV 1-3','INV 1-4','INV 2-1','INV 2-2','INV 2-3','INV 2-4',
 'INV 3-1','INV 3-2','INV 3-3','INV 3-4','INV 4-1','INV 4-2','INV 4-3','INV 4-4',
 'INV 5-1','INV 5-2','INV 5-3','INV 5-4','INV 6-1','INV 6-2','INV 6-3','INV 6-4',
 'INV 7-1','INV 7-2','INV 7-3','INV 7-4','INV 8-1','INV 8-2','INV 8-3','INV 8-4']
columns = ['P01','P02','P03','P04','P05','P06','P07','P08','P09','P10','P11']
heatMapInvdf = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
for area in areas:
    equipInArea = allEquipAllAreas.loc[:,allEquipAllAreas.columns.str.contains('P'+area+'-')]
    equipInArea = equipInArea.reindex(sorted(equipInArea.columns), axis=1).T
    equipInArea.index = equipInArea.index.str.replace(r'P'+area+'-', '')
    heatMapInvdf.merge(equipInArea,how='inner',right_index=True,left_index=True)
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I thought on: `heatMapInvdf.loc[equipInArea.index]['P01'] = equipInArea.values` but when printing heatMapInvdf the values are still NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have everything you want in your source DF.  Systematically re-shape it

- transpose
- index with multi-index which is splitting original column names
- `unstack()` to get structure you want
- `droplevel()` to clean up

```
import io
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""P01-INV-1-1 P01-INV-1-2 P01-INV-1-3 P01-INV-1-4 P11-INV-7-2 P11-INV-7-3 P11-INV-7-4
   -0.52       1.89         1.61        1.59        2.02        1.29       -0.89"""), sep="\s+")

heatMapInvdf = (
    # transpose for primary shape that is wanted
    df.T
    # index by multi-index which are from columns
    .set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(np.array([c.split("-", 1) for c in df.columns]).T))
    # unstack the P0n part of index
    .unstack(0)
    # remove transitent level from column index
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)

)
```

|  | P01 | P11 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INV-1-1 | -0.52 | nan |
| INV-1-2 | 1.89 | nan |
| INV-1-3 | 1.61 | nan |
| INV-1-4 | 1.59 | nan |
| INV-7-2 | nan | 2.02 |
| INV-7-3 | nan | 1.29 |
| INV-7-4 | nan | -0.89 |

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for your help, Rob!